# Highcharts BarChart Arabic longwords

Tags: highcharts, bar-chart, arabic

I am using **HighCharts** and when I type the xAxis categories with long name the text get mixed up as the 2 words mixed with each other as you see in the link:-

https://jsfiddle.net/Abdelrahmanlifestyle/zjubcLgx/8/

and the shown is

```
فواتيراء الكهرب
```

instead of

```
فواتير الكهرباء
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a High Charts bug, it's a Chrome bug. It works fine in Fire Fox. It's an old bug where it calculates the  positions of `<tspan>`s of RTL text wrongly. As a workaround you can use HTML for labels on axis.

```
labels: {
  useHTML: true
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zjubcLgx/15/